# Automatically change to power saving mode

Tags: power-management, 22.04

I'm using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS and I want to know if there is a way to automatically switch to power saving mode when battery is below a specific percentage. I know there is the "Automatic Power Saver" option but how can I set it to change when below, let's say, 30%?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/1311670/15811 only needs a check on the percentage.

Answer (score 0):

You can [check every minute with cron](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/577538/209677) if battery dropped below for e.g. 30% and run `systemctl suspend` or [change `scaling_governor`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1311670/349837) to powersave.

Also, maybe simpler, [using UPower](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/317933/209677).

To get related info:

```
cat /etc/UPower/UPower.conf | grep -v "^#" | egrep "Critical|Low|Action|Time"

gsettings list-recursively org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.power
```

To get suspend/hibernate support, use `pm-is-supported` from pm-utils package.

Answer (score 0):

At first turn on **Automatic Power Saver** [Turn on **Automatic Power Saver Option**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tsq74.png)
Then  open terminal and run this command and it will give the current settings for
auto power saving mode.

> **`cat /etc/UPower/UPower.conf | grep -v "^#" | egrep "Critical|Low|Action|Time"`**

Out put Should like below (consider the highlighted one i.e. **PercentageLow=**):

> ***PercentageLow=20***
> PercentageCritical=5
> PercentageAction=2
> TimeLow=1200
> TimeCritical=300
> TimeAction=120
> CriticalPowerAction=HybridSleep

Now edit "**/etc/UPower/UPower.conf**" to reflect the desired values(i.e. you have to change "**PercentageLow=20**" as "**PercentageLow=***30*****"(e.g. the change  value indicates that auto power saving mode will turn on when battery has ***30%*** left))

### processing to edit this file

**This required root priviledge**

1. **`sudo nano /etc/UPower/UPower.conf`**
2. Now find the line "**PercentageLow=20**" and edit it with the
   desired value in which point you want to auto power saving mode turn
   on(e.g.**PercentageLow=20** for **at 20%** or **PercentageLow=30**
   for **at 30%**)
3. After editing
4. Press <kbd>CTRL+O</kbd>
5. Press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
6. Press <kbd>CTRL+X</kbd>
7. **Reboot** or **Restart** your system.

Now your system will automatically turn on Power Saving Mode.